# Send JSON data to xmlhttp request using ASP Classic

Tags: json, curl, asp-classic

I need to send a CURL request using POST method and `json encoded data`. I am a `PHP` developer and I know how to do it in `PHP`. But in `ASP classic` I am facing problems. I created JSON data using [aspjson class](https://code.google.com/p/aspjson/wiki/Samples2) which looks like

```
{"apikey":"xxxxxxxx","id":"xxxxx","email":{"email":"myemail@email.com"},"merge_vars":{"fname":"BOB","phone":"xxxxx"},"email_type":"html","double_option":false}
```

My ASP code looks like

```
dim xmlhttp 
set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xmlhttp.Open "POST","https://someurl.com",false
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader"Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
xmlhttp.send data
getHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
response.write(getHTML)
xmlHttp.abort()
set xmlHttp = Nothing
```

I found following error

```
msxml3.dll error '80004002'
No such interface supported
/asptesting/curl.asp, line 48
```

48 line indicates `xmlhttp.send data`. When I use latest version of `MSXML` like this

```
set xmlhttp = server.Createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
```

I found followng error

```
msxml3.dll error '80070057'
The parameter is incorrect.
/asptesting/curl.asp, line 48
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Related to another unanswered question by the same user, [How to write this PHP CURL code in ASP classic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931168/how-to-write-this-php-curl-code-in-asp-classic).

Comment: @Lankymart What can a user do if his question is unanswered? BTW this is little bit different.

Comment: Agreed it is a bit different, does that mean your last question is no longer relevant? If so think about leaving an answer yourself for others who stumble across it. Also to answer your first question [What should I do if no one answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Not sure why you'd have your server-side do a xmlHTTP request. If both request and response belongs to the same domain, why don't you use AJAX?
It's faster, asynchronous (no page-reloading needed) and waaaay easier to handle (IMPOV). Info: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: @EricWu My dear read the question. He needs to send a CURL request. He didn't mention anywhere that he is sending request to same URL. When someone talks about `CURL` it means he is sending request to some other domain.

Comment: The editor of the question, please tell me where is the answer in that question?

Comment: @EricWu Lol, faster it's the same tech!, just one is running server side the other client side. Remember AJAX isn't some magic method it's just Asynchronous Calls (Javascript) over HTTP.

Comment: @AwaisQarni That also isn't true. CURL is just PHP implementation of the `libcurl` library, which allows client / server communication, be it two servers, the same server or anything with a open port that's listening for requests. XMLHTTP is exactly the same premise, they are equivalent.